# How do I use Next JS's Head tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've only just started looking at Next JS for my project but am having issues with the Head tag not working. According to the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head), I should just be able to import head from next/head and insert the title tag. However, it's not working for me, be it using the Layout component which gets imported to each page or directly injecting it.

Here is the code as a layout (/components/layout.jsx)

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Head from 'next/head';

export default function Layout({
    children,
    title = 'Default Title'
}) {
    return(
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>{title}</title>
                <meta charSet='utf-8' />
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"></link>
            </Head>
            <nav>
                <div className='nav-wrapper'>
                    <ul class='right hide-on-med-and-down'>
                        <li>
                            <Link href='/'>
                                <a>Home</a>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link href='/about'>
                                <a>About</a>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            {children}
            
            {/* Footer to go in here */}

            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And this is the about page (/pages/about.jsx)

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/layouts';

function About() {
    return(
        <Layout>
            <div>
                <h1>Test Page</h1>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default About;
```

It just doesn't work at all. The title is not updated and if I inspect the components, I can't see anything that I've added. I originally thought that it's because I set up the Next app myself and I did something wrong. However, I tried bootstrapping it with npx create-next-app and I am seeing the same issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 9):

**First**, create a new component, eg. `seo.jsx`

```
import Head from "next/head";

const SEO = ({ pageTitle, pageDescription }) => (
    <Head>
        <title>{pageTitle}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={pageDescription} />
        ...
    </Head>
);

export default SEO;
```

**Second**, import to your page (eg. `home.jsx`):

```
import SEO from "@components/seo"; //change to your path 

const Home = () => {
    ...
    return (
        <div>
            <SEO pageTitle="Homepage" pageDescription="Welcome to my website" />

            ...
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

In this scenario you will be able to change `title` and `description` (or any other `props` you need) in any page of your app, without worrying about `meta key` duplicates.

More info [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head).

Answer (score 0):

I took your exact code and created a sandbox and I can see the title working as expected **provided you use .jsx in your import**

> import Layout from '../components/layouts';

to
`import Layout from '../components/layouts.jsx';`

or if you want to use without extension, use `.js` instead

- **Code Sandbox - ** https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wind-4e035?file=/pages/index.js
- **Next JS Discussion** - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2391#issuecomment-311735189

I didn't do anything specific to the title but to make the sandbox work and to print the document title.

1. I modified paths without the folder and the default IndexPage  `next` sandbox
2. Modified `Index` to print the document title
3. Instead of importing  `components/layout`, imported `components/layout.jsx`

The Codesandbox crashed when i tried to import the file without the JSX extension.

Let me know if this helps or we can explore further!

Comment: Hmmm interesting. Mine definitely doesn't crash, just not working at all. I've also tried to import the <Head> tag directly from 'next/head' instead of going the Layout route and also didn't work. I'll try again tonight using the .jsx extension and let you know!

Comment: I meant to see use with a `.js` extension, instead of a jsx ? did you see my sandbox extension of your code?

Comment: I just tried importing it with .jsx extension and it doesn't work. Changing it all to .js doesn't work either.... odd because I checked out your code sandbox and it's working. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you post your project on a github or sandbox link ?

Comment: Hi Ramakay, here is the github link: https://github.com/ksoenandar/nextjs-test 

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine with the title - you can see in the browser toolbar (hover over the tab) , i modified to print `document.title` as well 
 and in element tab - https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-resonance-2e3pd?file=/pages/index.jsx - You can also see the deployed app here - https://2e3pd.sse.codesandbox.io/ - and here is the screenshot => https://imgur.com/a/Hq1SM5B

Comment: I restarted my laptop and it's now working...So odd but thanks for checking the code anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I also got that the head tag is not a working issue, what I did was added a  tag for cover  and the layout of the body
ex:

```
    <main>
      <head>
       {..head elements }
      </head>
      <div>
       { other elements }
      <div>
   </main>
```